# How to edit CPython's Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py?

Tags: python, compilation, cpython, python-importlib

I would like to play with CPython's Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py file, but my edits in my current CPython installation on MacOS (installed with the Homebrew package manager) have no effect when I import a module.

For instance if I add the `print("hello", file=sys.stderr)` statement at the beginning of the body of the `_init_module_attrs` function:

```
$ vi /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py
```

and then import a module:

```
$ python3 -c "import pathlib"
```

nothing is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`importlib._bootstrap` is a frozen module. To update it, the `importlib` module should be recompiled:

```
$ cd /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python/
$ make regen-importlib
$ make
```